# problems with the function (response)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I have made a page with jQuery mobile where I have a form. When I press submit it runs the following javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$("#formOpretKunde").submit(function(){
    var data = {};
    data.kundenummer    =$("#kundenummer").val();
    data.navn           =$("#navn").val();
    data.adresse        =$("#adresse").val();
    data.postnummer     =$("#postnummer").val();
    data.byNavn         =$("#byNavn").val();
    data.email          =$("#email").val();
    data.telefon        =$("#telefon").val();
    data.cvrCpr         =$("#cvrCpr").val();
    $.post("klasser/opretKunde.php", data, function(response)
    {
        if(response == "")
        {
            // Det gik godt
            alert("Kunde blev oprettet");
            $.mobile.changePage( "./index.html", { transition: "none"} );
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Fejl! Kunden blev ikke oprettet");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

});

It works fine and my data is entered into my database. The problem is with my function (response). It never enteres my if statement and I do not understand why. I've looked and looked and my responce should be empty?
What am I doing wrong?

Only thing I want to do is to create an alert that says the customer was created(Kunde blev oprettet) and then go to index.html when you press ok on the alert box.

Comment: Is there any whitespace in the response? View its length with `console.log(response.length)`.

Comment: A simple alert(response) in else case would do

Comment: hmmm its prints 2 then I use console.log(response.length)
What do I do now?

Comment: Well obviously your response is 2 characters long. It seems that you have whitespaces in your php answer. Check if at the end of your script <?php ?> if there is another whitespace or newline. This could solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use the jqXHR object returned by `$.post` which means you don't need to test the response object.

```
$.post("klasser/opretKunde.php", data )
.done( function( ) {

            // Det gik godt
            alert("Kunde blev oprettet");
            $.mobile.changePage( "./index.html", { transition: "none"} );
})
.fail( function( ) {

    alert("Fejl! Kunden blev ikke oprettet");
});
```

Comment: I do not quite understand what the difference is, which is probably not a good idea, since it is a school project I'm working on. But it works. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ajax function like this,

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "klasser/opretKunde.php",
    data: data,
    success: function(response) {
        if(response == "")
        {
            // Det gik godt
            alert("Kunde blev oprettet");
            $.mobile.changePage( "./index.html", { transition: "none"} );
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Fejl! Kunden blev ikke oprettet");
        }
    }
));
```